# Redirecting all non-HTTPS requests to HTTPS

Tags: linux, apache, url, ssl

I bought an SSL certificate for a website and followed the full installation procedure given by the vendor. It is now active and if I go to lets say `https://website.com` I get the desired result.

However, when someone tries `http://website.com` the request is not redirecting to `https://website.com`. I want that when someone enters `website.com` the request is automatically redirected to `https://www.website.com`.

I am using GoDaddy Linux server hosting. Please suggest what should I do to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also including SEO 301 redirections. Tested and works fine:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.site.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: last 2 lines is to redirect https://site.co.uk to https://www.site.co.uk. It is sometimes needed for SEO.